# How do you change the output of a T4 template from a base class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, t4

I want to create a tool as a base class to a T4 template for generating code at design time within Visual Studio .NET. I want my [TextTransformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation(v=vs.100).aspx) derived base class to have the final say as to what gets output into the generated file. The problem is that using .NET reflector I cannot find a method that I can override (or declare as new) or any event to hook into to change the contents of the GenerationEnvironment property before it gets used by the T4 framework.

Here is an example of the base class:

```
public class MyTool
    : TextTransformation
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // Initialize My Tool

        base.Initialize();
    }

    // Override the text that is generated from the T4 template and modify it 
    // (strip out some well known .NET attributes) here.

}
```

And it would be inherited from a T4 template like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" inherits="MyTool" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="MyTool.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyTool" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

[Ender]
public interface INinjaEnder
{
    INinja Build();
}

[Required]
public interface INinjaNamed<TRemainder>
{
    TRemainder Named(string name);
}

public interface INinjaCostume<TRemainder>
{
    TRemainder WithCostume(Costume costume);
}
```

I can hit breakpoints in the Initialize() method or the Dispose() method (when overridden) in MyTool, but there doesn't seem to be anything in between I can use for modifying the output. Some options I am considering:

1. Using the `Dispose()` method to create a separate file to output with the changed contents and just ignoring the output of the T4 template altogether. Unfortunately, generating a file with the same name in the `Dispose()` method doesn't work because it gets overwritten by the original text.
2. Forcing the end user to add a method call at the end of every template so I can run what I need to at the right time.
3. Override the `WriteLine()` and/or `Write()` methods (using new) and use them to strip out the text I don't want in the final file. This will likely entail RegEx matches on the output of the GenerationEnvironment so I can see if the code is in there and is completely generated before stripping it out.

I also thought of subclassing StringBuilder to override the ToString() method (the GenerationEnvironment returns a StringBuilder), but the StringBuilder class is sealed.

I should mention that I am targeting all editions (including express editions) of Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013. I noticed that there were some pretty big differences in T4 between 2010 and 2012, so I need to come up with a solution that works in both environments.

**Some Context**

My reasons for going down this path are:

1. T4 is supported by express editions, custom tools (IVsSingleFileGenerator) and designers are not. A large part of my target audience (open source developers) will likely be using an express edition.
2. I want the user to specify the input as code (interfaces and attributes through the T4 template) so they don't have a steep learning curve to use my tool by having to input something more abstract such as XML, diagrams, or a designer.
3. I don't want the user to have to set a reference to my DLL (and thus have to ship the DLL with their code) in order to use my tool. Using T4 I can strip the attributes out of the final code after the generator is done using them, so only my tool needs to have a reference to the attributes.
4. T4 supports dependency injection through property injection of the base class, so my users will be able to supply their own extensions to my tool.
5. I can support both VB and C# T4 templates without creating too much duplicate code (since most of it will be in my DLL).

However, I will accept architectural advice if there is a better choice available than a T4 base class.